# Query input must contain at least one table or query error

Tags: ms-access, java

I'm working on a java program that connects to a Microsoft Access database and displays the data in a GUI. I'm currently trying to code a button that adds a new row to a table called `Grade` that holds grades for students that exist in another table called `Student` for courses that exist in a third table called `Course`.

The condition for adding a new grade is that the student and course already exist in another table. I thought I had gotten the SQL statement right but when I run it, an error in access appears that says "Query must contain at least one table or query".

Here is my SQL statement:

`INSERT INTO Grade (StudentID,CourseID,Semester,Year,Grade) 
VALUES((SELECT StudentID FROM Student WHERE StudentID = 5812356),(SELECT CourseID FROM Course WHERE CourseID = 'CS101'), 'Fall', '2016','B');`

The `StudentID` and `CourseID` specified exist in the `Student` and `Course` tables.

I don't understand this error since I have specified which table I'm trying to add to and I have written out a query.

I appreciate any help given.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got your `VALUES` clause a bit mixed up.

Is this what you're after?

```
INSERT INTO Grade 
       (StudentID, CourseID, Semester, Year, Grade) 
SELECT s.StudentID, c.CourseID, 'Fall', '2016','B'
FROM Student s
JOIN Course c
ON s.StudentId = c.StudentId
WHERE s.StudentID = 5812356
AND c.CourseID = 'CS101';
```